# How to make a script that interacts with screen lock / unlock

Tags: scripts, lock-screen, dbus

I need a script for when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Lock screen)
I blocked or shut down all usb's and shut down all my network interfaces like `eth0`.

When I Unlock, everything should be back to normal. I tried

```
echo suspend> / sys / bus / usb / devices / usb1 / power / level
```

.. but I could not ..

And also

```
dbus-monitor --session "type = 'signal', interface = 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
```

to interact with the screen but could not too.

Is there any better method? Or something I can study to create this script?

Comment: better approach would be to bind a script to the ctrl+alt+L shortcut , which will do whatbyou want and only then lock the screen. I would do that but lately i am short on time. Perhaps someone else can do this. If not, i might come back and write one

Comment: I just want a script for when I lock the screen, disable all USB ports and my interfaces like eth0.
I tried to use something like, dbus-monitor --session "type = 'signal', interface = 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
  While read x; of
    Case "$ x" in
      * "Boolean true" * echo suspend> / sys / bus / usb / devices / usb1 / power / level ......

But it does not work

Comment: @nullXOR posted my answer. Please mention if all is clear.

Answer (score 2):

#### How to run scripts or commands on changes in lock state

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211863/95917) on U&L, you tried an outdated `dbus` command. For 14.04 and up, you can use:

```sh
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6'" | \
(
  while read X; do
    if [[ "$X" =~ desktop-lock ]]; then
      SCREEN_LOCKED;
    elif [[ "$X" =~ desktop-unlock ]]; then
      SCREEN_UNLOCKED;
    fi
  done
)
```

which works fine on my system (16.04). 
(Thanks for improvements by @Serg and @muru)

Of course you need to replace `SCREEN_LOCKED` and `SCREEN_UNLOCKED` by the commands or scripts you want to run on changes in lock state, but tested it, and it works fine.

Comment: If you're using bash, you can simplify it to `if [[ $X =~ desktop-lock ]]; then ..` (and similarly for the other one). And maybe use `while read X` instead of `while true` (does the read ever fail other than when the dbus-monitor process exits?)

Comment: doesn't seem to work on ubuntu 17.04. The ouput of `dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6'"` is `signal time=1497336035.520628 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.140 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.140"
signal time=1497336035.520706 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.140 serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.140"`, then nothing when I lock or unlock