# media shortcut and media commands not work ubuntu 19.04 unity

Tags: command-line, unity, shortcut-keys, 19.04, media-buttons

I'm using unity desktop on Ubuntu 19.04

But the media shortcut not work I search and do this solution:

[media keys no longer work in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983676/media-keys-no-longer-work-in-ubuntu-17-10)

[Keyboard shortcuts don't work on Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081241/keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-unity)

Now I try to do it with command lines:

```
Play:

dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Play

Pause:

dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause

Play/Pause toggle:

dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause

Previous:

dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous

Next:

dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
```

but I have this error :

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify was not provided by any .service files
```

wtf,I search in repo:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2

and do this:

```
sudo apt-get install mopidy-mpris mpdris2 -y
```

Now why the commands not work? 
Is the medias key not work related to this command?

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install `mpd` Music Player Daemon:

[reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPD)

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mpd sonata
```

Comment: It's not working for me. The above mentioned commands do work when typed into the terminal though (Ubuntu 18.04 with unity desktop installed)